# Grepping archive logs with grep, awk, and a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to extract some counts from tomcat catalina.out logs & able to extract count from single catalina.out file.  I used the command below

```
  grep "WHAT: " /appl/cas/tomcat/logs/catalina.out | awk -F'for ' '{if($2=="") print $1; else print $2;}' | awk -F'WHAT: ' '{if($2=="") print $1; else print $2;}' | sort | uniq -c
```

which is giving expected results like

```
 1 http://whiteyellowpages.com/whiteyellowpages/commonpage.do?locale=fr&advanced=no&search.name=oujdial
 1 http://whiteyellowpages.com/whiteyellowpages/commonpage.do?locale=fr&advanced=no&search.name=OUKHOUIA
```

I want to extract some counts from archive logs of catalina.out, with a  filename format of: `2015-03-24_03:50:50_catalina.out` ... and so on.

I used the same command with `*_catalina.out` as below:

```
grep "WHAT: " /appl/cas/tomcat/logs/*_catalina.out | awk -F'for ' '{if($2=="") print $1; else print $2;}' | awk -F'WHAT: ' '{if($2=="") print $1; else print $2;}' | sort | uniq -c
```

which is giving correct results, but I want to add filename which are processing above command. The expected result is:

```
  2015-03-24_03:50:50_catalina.out 1 http://whiteyellowpages.com/whiteyellowpages/commonpage.do?locale=fr&advanced=no&search.name=oujdial
  2015-03-24_03:50:50_catalina.out 1 http://whiteyellowpages.com/whiteyellowpages/commonpage.do?locale=fr&advanced=no&search.name=OUKHOUIA
```

I tried `grep` with `-H` & `-l` options but no success. Can you help with this?

Sample logs

```
  2015-03-23 03:43:52,987 INFO  [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][AuthenticationManagerImpl:96] org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JCIFSSpnegoAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated SV003006$
2015-03-23 03:43:52,988 DEBUG [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][SpnegoCredentialsToPrincipalResolver:54] Attempting to resolve a principal...
2015-03-23 03:43:52,989 DEBUG [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][SpnegoCredentialsToPrincipalResolver:64] Creating SimplePrincipal for [SV003006$]
2015-03-23 03:43:52,989 DEBUG [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][LdapPersonAttributeDao:103] Created seed map='{username=[SV003006$]}' for uid='SV003006$'
2015-03-23 03:43:52,990 DEBUG [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][LdapPersonAttributeDao:301] Adding attribute 'sAMAccountName' with value '[SV003006$]' to query builder 'null'
2015-03-23 03:43:52,990 DEBUG [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][LdapPersonAttributeDao:328] Generated query builder '(sAMAccountName=SV003006$)' from query Map {username=[SV003006$]}.
2015-03-23 03:43:52,992 INFO  [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][AuthenticationManagerImpl:119] Resolved principal SV003006$
2015-03-23 03:43:52,993 INFO  [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][AuthenticationManagerImpl:61] org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JCIFSSpnegoAuthenticationHandler@4a23d87f authenticated SV003006$ with credential SV003006$.
2015-03-23 03:43:52,993 DEBUG [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][AuthenticationManagerImpl:62] Attribute map for SV003006$: {}
2015-03-23 03:43:52,994 INFO  [http-apr-10.155.50.93-4443-exec-4][Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager:41] Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: SV003006$
WHAT: supplied credentials: SV003006$
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Mon Mar 23 03:43:52 CET 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.155.70.144
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.155.50.93
=============================================================
```

Comment: can you please share the sample log file

Comment: Which stage of the pipeline is failing? You could replace each `|` with a write to intermediate file (eg `> tempN` where `N` changes for the different pipes) a command separator (eg newline) and a pipe intermediate in to next stage (eg `cat tempN |`). Then examine the contents of the various tempN files.

Comment: I am able to print something like this filename1 <newLine> all the logs of that file than filename2 <newLine> all the logs of that file and so on... May be if you can provide a sample log file i can help

Comment: If I understand correctly, seeing the logfile content won't help. The problem is not the content of the log, but the output of grep. `grep -l` will output the filename in which a match was found, but the awk then cuts out this same information. The key is printing the filename next to the awked log line.

Comment: "but the awk then cuts out this same information" thats the reason i need to know the log contents because now we would need three awk commands and to know the delimiter for third command we need to know a sample log statement

Comment: sample log file updated

Comment: Why does this question have the [Perl] and [sed] tags?

Comment: any possibility of regex

Comment: The output based on logs attached and your command is:        1 supplied credentials: SV003006. hope this correct because the output content that you have added looks a bit different

Comment: Ya both output correct